# Mule 3.7.3 and Jackson 2.9.0 issues-NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, jackson, mule, jackson2

I am having lots of issues getting Mule to work with Jackson classes. The classes present in my final library only have the following files. To eliminate the possibility of maven pulling in other jackson libraries, I create a mule project without using maven and simply pull in the bare minimum libraries. However, it is failing with `NoSuchMethodError` for `CSVMapper().reader(MyClass)` etc. and later with

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
               com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.<init>
         (Ljava/io/Closeable;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

jackson-core-2.9.0.jar
  jackson-databind-2.9.0.jar
  jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
  jackson-dataformat-csv-2.9.0.jar

I get `NoSuchMethodError`  when I call methods that are definitely in the classpath. To make matters worse the program runs fine outside of Mule.

It turns out that the following module mule-core.3.7.3 has an older version of Jackson i.e. 2.4.3. Unfortunately what works with version 2.9.0 now fails with

```
 Too many entries: expected at most 1 (value #1 (18 chars) "20170822211046.581")
```

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Your questions seems confused. What are the listing of modules for? (jackson-core, jackson-databind, etc.) How do you run your program outside of Mule, and you do you deploy it to Mule? What is the other thing with 2.9.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  solved it by using the Jackson libraries provided by Mule i.e. version 2.4.3 for converted JSON to Java objects. For the CSV conversion to Map I used apache commons-csv replacing Jackson's CSVMapper.